# Extracting value from JSON using jolt transformation

Tags: json, transformation, jolt

I have a JSON object:

```json
{
  "Data": "{field1: [x,y],field2: z}"
}
```

Desired Output JSON:

```json
{
  "field3": "z"
}
```

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Data": {
        "*field2:*}*": {
          "$(0,2)": "field3"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Here the value of `"Data"` is a complete string not a JSON, hence I have to break it into wildcards and now the 2nd `'*'` in the spec gives me the value `"z"`.

Is there any better approach to do the same such that say a new field comes before or after field2 then I don't have to modify this regex.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly this doesn't feel like problem to be solved in JOLT, and instead the `Data` should be extracted and serialized to JSON.

That said i've managed to get something to work, explanation inline:

```
[
  //Remove {
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Data": {
        "{*": {
          "$(0,1)": "Data"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  //Remove }
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Data": {
        "*}": {
          "$(0,1)": "Data"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  // Split by ,
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "Data": "=split(',', @(2,Data))"
    }
  },
  // Trim
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "Data": {
        "*": "=trim"
      }
    }
  },
  // Select field2
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Data": {
        "*": {
          "field2:*": {
            "$(0,1)": "field3"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  // Trim again
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=trim"
    }
  }
]
```

Tested against:

```
{
  "Data": "{field1: [x,y], field2: z}"
}
```

and

```
{
  "Data": "{ field2: z, field1: [x,y]}"
}
```

and

```
{
  "Data": "{field1: [x,y], field2: z, field3: [x,y]}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed current case is pretty good, you're so close, just need two modifications to
the current key (**`"*field2:*}*"`**) should be applied such that

- Remove the asterisk at the end. Since, it expects at least one character following **`}`**, and fails in the current case
- Leave one whitespace before second asterisk to prune the resultant literal **`"z"`** rather than **`" z"`**

So, convert **`"*field2:*}*"`** to **`"*field2: *}"`**

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Data": {
        "*field2: *}": {
          "$(0,2)": "field3"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

or you can use the literal **`fiel`** after reshaping the key as follows and get the same result

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Data": {
        "*],*d2: *}": {
          "$(0,3)": "&(1,2)d3"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```